# array_count_values used with array_filter reaching allowed memory size

Tags: php, arrays, explode, array-filter

I need an advice how to rewrite a piece of PHP code, so that it is more efficient on memory usage.

**Code Description:** I am fetching comma separated values (like a,b,c,d) from `MySQL` and adding each of them in a new comma separated string via `while loop`. After that I use `array_count_values(array_filter(explode(',',$string)` in order to get the count of times each different value is contained in the string.

The code itself works. However, for massive arrays, PHP returns an error `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 524288000 bytes exhausted` and I need to find a solution for it.

Note: I would like to avoid assigning a higher `memory_limit` in php.ini or via `ini_set`. What I am looking for is a solution that will give the same result but without having to deal with memory issues. I was thinking that I can record the value count on each loop but somehow I cannot find the right way to do it.

Any suggestions?

```
$options    = '';
while(!$rs_results->EOF){
   $options .= $rs_results->fields['options'].",";
$rs_results->MoveNext();
}

$arrOptions = array_count_values(array_filter(explode(',', $options)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just count while you go?

```
$options = [];
while (!$rs_results->EOF) {
    if ($rs_results->fields['options']) {
        foreach (explode(',', $rs_results->fields['options']) as $value) {
            if (!isset($options[$value])) $options[$value] = 0;
            ++$options[$value];
        }
    }
}
```

Obligatory observation that [storing data this way is generally a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad). If you had a normalised structure you could just `COUNT` them in MySQL.